# Convert Object to int without rounding

Tags: c#, object, int

I have to convert an object to int. My object values is something like 1.34535
What I need is the first part which is (1).

I tried the followings:
- `Convert.ToInt32(myObj.Value)`, it rounds the number. if it's `1.78`, I got it (2) which is wrong. I need only the integer of first part.

- `int.TryParse(myObj.Value.toString(), out outValue)`
  I got it `0` for all values!
- `int.Parse(myObj.Value.toString())` throws an exception, that is in incorrect format.

Comment: What if the value is 13.4535, do you still need just the "1" part or the "13"?

Comment: What is the source type of that object?

Comment: what *is* the object? would calling `Math.Floor` on the input in the natural type, *then* casting to int: work?

Comment: `(int)((double)(myObj.Value))` if `myObj.Value` is boxed `double`

Comment: @E. Hoxha, no I need the (13). I ment I need the first part before the dot.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko It worked! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `myObj.Value` is *boxed* `double` then you have to cast *twice*: to *unbox* back into `double` and then in order to truncate into `int`:

```
int result = (int)((double)(myObj.Value)):
```

In general case, try `Convert`; the idea is the same: first restore the orignal `double` and then obtain required `int`:

```
int result = (int) (Convert.ToDouble(myObj.Value));
```

**Edit:** in the implementation above I've read *without rounding* request as *truncated*, i.e. fractional part should be *ignored*:

```
 2.4 ->  2
-2.4 -> -2
```

If different behaviour is expected, e.g.

```
 2.4 ->  2
-2.4 -> -3
```

one can add `Math.Floor` e.g.

```
 int result = (int) (Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(myObj.Value)));
```

Comment: I think, this solution is not working for negative numbers. (int)((double)(-2.4)) will be -2.

Comment: @Rainman: well, the question doesn't specify what should be done with *negative numbers*. I suggested *truncating*: `2.42 -> 2`, `-2.4 -> -2` (fractional part *ignored). If it's not the desired behaviour (`-2.4` should be chnaged into `-3`) `Math.Floor` can be added: `(int) (Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(myObj.Value)));`

Comment: It seems to me that the OP desired less one of the double number. Whatever, the OP should decide it.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to `double` it first;

```
var doubleValue = double.Parse(myObj.Value.ToString());
//It could be better to use double.TryParse
int myInt = (int)Math.Floor(doubleValue);
```

Comment: It will round the less one. Math.Floor(-2.4) is -3.

Comment: this answer is incorrect, it would not work for negative numbers

Comment: "it would not work for negative numbers" what is that mean ? If you want to round number to less one use "Floor" if you want to take first part only use "Truncate". It depends for the requirements.

Comment: The requirement in the question was clearly defined as "the integer of first part", not to round one less..

Answer (score 1):

Convert your object to a double value and use Use `Math.Truncate(number)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2eabd70.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Very easy, don't forget to wrap it in `try` and `catch`:

```
int i = (int)Math.Truncate(double.Parse(myObj.ToString()));
```

`Math.Truncate` just cuts off the numbers after the comma like:

`4.434` becomes `4`

`-43.65445` becomes `-43`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this is also a solution :

```
var integer = int.Parse(myObject.Value.ToString().Split('.').First());
```